# Issues with maven and jboss demo app "Ticket-Monster"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I cloned this repository from github https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/continuous-delivery-demo-app

I ran mvn clean package but get the following error:

[image]

I configured settings.xml as on the link below
[settings.xm](http://pastebin.com/6vh0J5Qw)

Im usin Intellij Idea with maven apache-maven-3.3.3 and pointing to the defaut settings.xml(modified as mentioned)

I have the same error when running outside Intellij Idea

Running with mvn -X clean package (see settings.xml is being read)
[image: mvn -X clean package]

Running with mvn clean package
[image: mvn clean package]

```
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\j
boss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-6.2.3.GA
.pom: end tag name </span> must match start tag name <img> from line 177 (positi
on: START_TAG seen ...ccess.redhat.com/chrome_themes/nimbus/img/l_redhat-lg.png"
></span>... @177:118)  @ C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\jb
oss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-6.2.3.GA.
pom, line 177, column 118
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\j
boss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy-6.2.3.GA.p
om: end tag name </span> must match start tag name <img> from line 177 (position
: START_TAG seen ...ccess.redhat.com/chrome_themes/nimbus/img/l_redhat-lg.png"><
/span>... @177:118)  @ C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\jbos
s-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy-6.2.3.GA.pom,
 line 177, column 118
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:
jar is missing. @ line 210, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelge
n:jar is missing. @ line 227, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackso
n-provider:jar is missing. @ line 264, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:
jar is missing. @ line 269, column 21
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.jboss.examples:ticket-monster:2.6.88-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev-
world\lab-world\continuous-delivery-demo-app\pom.xml) has 6 errors
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\e
ap\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-6.2.
3.GA.pom: end tag name </span> must match start tag name <img> from line 177 (po
sition: START_TAG seen ...ccess.redhat.com/chrome_themes/nimbus/img/l_redhat-lg.
png"></span>... @177:118)  @ C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\ea
p\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-6.2.3
.GA.pom, line 177, column 118 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\e
ap\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy-6.2.3.
GA.pom: end tag name </span> must match start tag name <img> from line 177 (posi
tion: START_TAG seen ...ccess.redhat.com/chrome_themes/nimbus/img/l_redhat-lg.pn
g"></span>... @177:118)  @ C:\Users\iguissouma\.m2\repository\org\jboss\bom\eap\
jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy\6.2.3.GA\jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy-6.2.3.GA.
pom, line 177, column 118 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-valida
tor:jar is missing. @ line 210, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamod
elgen:jar is missing. @ line 227, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-ja
ckson-provider:jar is missing. @ line 264, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-ja
xrs:jar is missing. @ line 269, column 21
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseExce
ption
```

Any one has an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Your `settings.xml` looks correct. Does it work if you build it outside IntelliJ? Is Maven using the right `settings.xml`? I just tested and was able to clone and build the project without error.

Comment: Have the same error outside of Intellij Idea, when I execute mvn with -X flag, I see that mvn is pointing to the correct settings.xml!!

Comment: Don't post images of your error message, you should instead post the stacktrace as text.

Comment: I have the exact same setup as you but I am not reproducing your error.

Comment: It's really strange, I'm using Windows 8.1, maven-3.3.3, IDEA 14.1.4, I'll check on other computers!! maybe it will work!